# Как перенести данные из строки в ссылку в HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, html5, html-form, site

Задача следующая: 
необходимо перенести данные из поля ввода `<input>` или `<form>` в `<button href="createdby/*введённые данные*">`.
 Возможно ли такое сделать на HTML/PHP с/без использования JS?

Comment: до формы отправки на сервер, или после?

Comment: @Ипатьев, после

Comment: Ну и какая проблема тупо добавить вместо *введённые данные* код вывода переменной?

Answer (score 0):

отправляйте форму через POST, а в ссылку вставляйте все необходимые данные.

href="createdby/<?=$_POST['name введённых данных']">

Answer (score 0):

Вижу один способ, отправить на сервер, получить ответ от сервера, поместить данные в кнопку

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]